# JS - jquery (UI) - starting autocompletion from an external call

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

If got a problem with my remote datasource autocompletion field:

```
$( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "xxxx",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        y:  y,
                        x:  x,
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        response(data);
                    }
                });
            },
        minLength: 0,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            alert( ui.item ?
                "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
        }
    }).live("click", function() {
         $(this).trigger('keydown.autocomplete');
    });
```

the .live("click") works well, but only for the first click. If I selected an result from the list and leave the focus clicking events are brocken. With key-actions there are no probs.
Don't see anything in the console.

Thanks for help, Noma

--> SORRY for the bad english (2 years aren't engouh)

Answer (score 0):

Which version are you using of autocomplete?

Try using a more simple code

```
$("#birds").autocomplete("xxxx", {
        width: 400,
        dataType: 'json',
        highlight: false,
        scroll: true,
        scrollHeight: 400,
        parse: function(data) {
                var array = new Array();
                for(var i=0;i<data.items.length;i++)
                {
                        array[array.length] = { data: data.items[i], value: data.items[i], result: data.items[i].username };
                }
                return array;
        },

        formatItem: function(row) {                     
                var name = '';
                if (row.first_name && row.last_name)
                        name = '('+row.first_name+', '+row.last_name+')';
                else if (row.first_name)
                        name = '('+row.first_name+')';
                else if (row.last_name)
                        name = '('+row.last_name+')';

                return row.username+' '+name;
        }
    });
```

Obviously replace the key values to match your json output

Comment: I'm using 1.8.13

But in your solution i can not start the autocompletion by clicking (or focus) on the element as an event...?